# Remove the bounce effect from table view on scrolling

Tags: swift, uitableview, uiscrollview

[image]I tried by uncheck the "vertical bounce" but it disable the scroll also.. My table View cell is hiding behind.

Comment: where its hiding?

Comment: Take a good look under the Attributes Inspector.

Comment: behind the footer view.

Answer (score 1):

Set tableview.bounces = false this will disable the bouncing.

Answer (score 0):

make sure the bottom anchor/constraint is above the tab bar

Comment: Table view is inside the container View and the container's  bottom constraint is set with the top of the bottom tab view. Then also the tableView is hiding behind the tab, not getting whats wrong.